# How to Add label to uibutton in Swift?

Tags: ios, uibutton, label

I want to achieve that look of my button as shown? The right side of button which contains arrow (>) needs to be a simple label with that text. How can i do that? Is there anyway? I have checked many possibilities like taking a UIView and then adding button and labels inside it. I wanna know is that the only solution or there exist any other good one. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Masonry or SnapKit ? Try this:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = ">"
button.addSubview(label)
label.snp.makeConstraints {
    $0.right.equalToSuperview()
    $0.centerY.equalToSuperview()
}
```

Comment: No. I haven't used that before. Looks like i have to now. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var hotelButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let lab = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 3, width: 50, height: 50))
        lab.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 32)
        lab.text = ">"
        hotelButton.addSubview(lab)